# Landscape orientation is not supported in ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I want to make a screen in landscape mode only. It is work fine unto ios5. But in iOS 7 it is not working. I used following code to give support in ios7.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{return TRUE;}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;}
```

It won't get call for all screens.
Thanks.
AKS.

Comment: the system will ask the root viewController to get the orientation info. make sure your code is in the rootVC

Comment: i wrote this code in view controller.m. It got call in first time. But didn't get call after navigating to next screen.

Comment: you use UINavigationController to move from A to B? if so, you should subclass UINavigationController, and write the code there. the code you write in A won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is it is not getting call when navigate to next screen.

Comment: From your root controller, call shouldAutorotate in your viewController. if you are using a navigationcontroller you can get the controller showed with [self.navigationcontroller topViewController]. In your shouldAutorotate in rootViewController write "[topviewcontroller shouldAutorotate];"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, I wrote a blog post about it. I was having a lot of trouble with this too. http://www.jmeveryday.com/ios7-device-orientation/